# async.series nested in async.eachSeries loop terminates early sending POST response

Tags: arrays, node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I am on the recieving end of a POST call which contains an array of objects (requestArray). Before I respond to the POST, I need to pass the array's objects through a series of functions, in sequence. I chose the async library to help me with this task however I'm having difficulty controlling the code's execution flow.

I am using a global array to store the results of each function (responseArray). Some of the functions depend on the result of prior functions. I don't want to use async.waterfall() because 1. I'll have to rewrite my code and 2. I may encounter the same early loop termination issue. Below is my code problematic code.

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  var importArray = req.body;
  var iteration = 0;

  async.eachSeries(importArray, function(data, callback) {
    var index = importArray.indexOf(data);
    var element  = data.element;
    exportArray[index] = [];

    async.series([
      function(callback) {
        process1(data, index, callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        process2(element, index, callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        process3(element, index, callback);
      }],
      function(err, results) {  
        var str = {};
        results.forEach(function(result) {
          if (result) {
              str += result + ',';
          }
        });
        //callback();       // callback here = synchronous execution.
        if (index === req.body.length - 1) {
          res.send(exportArray);
        }
      });
      console.log('async.eachSeries() callback iteration # = ' + iteration);
      iteration++;
      callback();           // callback here = asynchronous execution.
  }, function(err){
      if( err ) {
        console.log('Error');
      } else {
        console.log('All data has been processes successfully.');
      }
  });
});
```

Each function in the async.series() returns callback(null, result). After process1() returns its callback, the async.eachSeries() jumps to the next array entry before, which is ideal. However, async.eachSeries() executes a POST response before all of the async.series() results are returned. How could I revise my code so that async.eachSeries() finishes execution after all of the importArray results (exportArray) are returned from process1 - 3 before I send a POST response?

Comment: Being a little older and wiser I realize the problem with early `async.eachSeries()` loop termination is due my mistake of inserting the asynchronous method `results.forEach()` at the end of the `async.series()` method. Instead of `results.forEach()`, I should've used a synchronous method like a `for()` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest for ease of following the async nature of your code to rename your callbacks slightly. Also to wait until eachSeries has finished move `res.send` to `eachSeries` final callback passing in the `results`.

Here is the updated code.

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  var importArray = req.body;
  var iteration = 0;

  async.eachSeries(importArray, function(data, next) {
    var index = importArray.indexOf(data);
    var element  = data.element;
    exportArray[index] = [];

    async.series([
      function(cb) {
        process1(data, index, cb);
      },
      function(cb) {
        process2(element, index, cb);
      },
      function(cb) {
        process3(element, index, cb);
      }],

      function(err, results) {  
        var str = {};
        results.forEach(function(result) {
          if (result) {
              str += result + ',';
          }
        });

        console.log('async.eachSeries() callback iteration # = ' + iteration);
        iteration++;
        next(null, results);      
      });     

  }, function(err, results){
      if(err) {
        return console.log('Error');
      } 

      res.send(exportArray);
      console.log('All data has been processes successfully.');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for revising, Bulkan. `next(null, results)` is throwing an error because `results` is not in scope. Also, should I have 2 `res.send(exportArray)` statements?

Comment: I was able to implement your changes and it works correctly. However, it does run synchronously. I'm copying my code that I got to run asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

After help from @Bulkan and tinkering, I got the code to run asynchronously with the help of my old friend, "flag". Here's the code:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  var importArr = req.body;
  var iteration = 0;
  var flag      = false;

  async.eachSeries(importArr, function(data, cb) {
    var index        = importArr.indexOf(data);
    var element      = data.element;
    exportArr[index] = [];

    async.series([
      function(cb) {
        process1(data, index, cb);
      },
      function(cb) {
        process2(element, index, cb);
      },
      function(cb) {
        process3(element, index, cb);
      }],

      function(err, results) {  
        var str = {};
        results.forEach(function(result) {
          if (result) {
              str += result + ',';
          }
        });
        iteration++;
        if (iteration === req.body.length) {
          flag = true;
          res.send(exportArr);
        } 
      });
      console.log('async.eachSeries() callback iteration # = ' + iteration);

      if (iteration < req.body.length) {
        cb();
      } else if (flag)  {
        cb();
      }
  }, function(err){
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error');
      } else {
        console.log('All data has been processes successfully.');
      }
  });
});
```